# Guaranteeing immutability in c#

Tags: c#, immutability

After reading a lot about immutability in C#, and understading it's benefits (no side effects, safe dictionary keys, multithreading...) a question has come to my mind:

Why there is not a keyword in C# for asserting that a class (or struct) is immutable? This keyword should check at compile time that there is no way you can mutate the class (or struct). For example:

```
public immutable class MyImmutableClass
{
    public readonly string field;

    public string field2; //This would be a compile time error

    public readonly AnyMutableType field3; //This would be a compile time error


    public string Prop { get; }

    public string Prop2 { get; set; } //This would be a compile time error

    public AnyMutableType Prop3 { get; } //This would be a compile time error
}
```

I think the compiler work would be quite easy, as it would need to check just a few things:

- All public fields are readonly.
- All public properties only have getters.
- All public fields or properties have immutable types as well (simple value types, or immutable classes/structs).
- All public functions or public property getters only depend on immutable fields or properties (public fields/props as described before, or private fields/props which comply to the same restrictions). This of course includes Equals(), GetHashCode() and ToString().

Some possible problems come to my mind with this design:

- For the compiler to know that a compiled class/struct is immutable, it would probably be necesary to make changes in the intermediate language.
- Readonly generic collection (such as `IEnumerable<T>`) immutability would depend on the immutability of the type `<T>`. The proposed `immutable` keyword would not be useful in this context, as you could not declare that `IEnumerable<string>` is immutable, even though it is.

Are the reasons stated before enough for this keyword to not exist?
Am I missing any other drawbacks?
Is this just not necessary enough for such big changes in the language?

Comment: [https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/159](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/159) - proposal for immutable types.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think that one is unlikely, but there's a `readonly struct` proposal that is being driven by the `readonly ref` stuff that is very likely for C# 7.something

Comment: @MarcGravell - I think that's probably the one I was half-remembering, but my search on immutable found the one I've linked to.

Comment: dammit, was about to post an answer; I've dumped it in a gist instead - there might be some interesting info there: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/03dcf34005945fa494998c089e7246a5; for the record, because there *is* context here, I disagree that it is purely opinion based - but I'm not going to vote to reopen, because my votes are automatically binding...

Comment: Thanks for the info! There's certainly good stuff happening in C#7. Immutability in structs would be awesome. I also don't understand why the question would be opinion based, if anyone can help me to improve the question...

Comment: We can also add `public singleton class MySingletonClass` or smth like `public dto class MyDTOClass`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short version would be: because nobody has proposed, spec'd, designed, implemented, tested, documented, translated and supported that feature.

The longer version would relate to *why* to do it, given that it can be achieved indirectly with the `readonly` field - what *benefit* would it add.

For classes, it turns out to be *relatively* minor. Note that there is an `[ImmutableObject(true)]` attribute that *can* be used, but no features or frameworks really have a use for it, so ... nobody uses it.

There *was* a proposal to add "readonly structs" in a future version of C# (related to `ref` locals, `Span<T>`, etc) - but: it died a death and evaporated. However, the `ref readonly` stuff lives on, which is intended to prevent reassignment of `this` in `struct` instance methods.